# how to create schema for a person with unique and multiple phone numbers in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to node js and mongodb, I want to create a schema as -

- Person have a Name (required)
- Will/Can have multiple phone numbers (should have at least 1 phone number)
- Will/Can have multiple emails
- Will/Can have single Date of birth (not mandatory)

Constraints

- Two contacts cannot have same phone numbers
- Two contacts can have the same emails

I know I can save multiple phone numbers in mongodb with array but I am confused how to make sure that two contacts not have same phone number ?

Should I create another schema for phone number and assign a foreign key to person or I can simply use array ?

What is the best way to do so ?

Comment: https://thinkster.io/tutorials/node-json-api/creating-the-user-model

Comment: To check that two contacts not have same phone number , you should check every time the new user don't have his phone number already insert  in DB .

Should I create another schema for phone number and assign a foreign key to person or I can simply use array ? No , because this kind of modeling is for a relational DB

Comment: @YasBES are you saying I should save phone numbers in array ? If yes then should I check manually if any phone number matches with any phone number of other user ??

Comment: Yes you can use an array or an object check this link for more details : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200017/mongodb-array-vs-object

Comment: Yes you can do it easly in mongo db.your_collection.find({ $in : "13131313","$phones"}) it will return true or false . Check the documentation for more details : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/

Comment: I recommand you to do this course : https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M001/about

Answer (score 2):

### Using MongoDB with NodeJS,

You can utilize the mongoose library and create schema as follows

**Mongoose schema definition:** use `[] for Array` and a `validate` property

```
const phoneSchema = new Schema({
    type: String,
    match: [/^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$/, 'Enter a valid phone number']
}

const emailSchema = new Schema({
    type: String,
    match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, 'Enter a valid email address']
}

const minimumLimit= function(val) {
    return val.length >= 1;
}

const contactSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    birthDate: Date,
    phone: { 
        type: [ phoneSchema ], index: true, unique: true,
        validate: [minimumLimit, 'Enter at least one phone number']
    },
    email: { type: [ emailSchema ] }
});
```

**Alternate way to define Index using Mongosh:** use `createIndex` command

```
db.contacts.createIndex({phone: 1}, {unique: true})
```

1. The above snippets will create a unique index for the Phone field in
   the Contacts collection.
2. Since the Phone field is an array, the
   uniqueness will be applicable across all documents in the Contacts
   collection
3. So any two documents in the Contacts collection will not have same phone number

**Restrict Contact Document from having duplicate email or phone number in single document:**

Use `$addToSet` and `$each` operator

```
db.contacts.update(
   { _id: 43 },
   { 
       $addToSet: { 
           phone: { 
               $each: [ "445566", "445577", "445588" ]
           }
       }
   }
)
```

Comment: Is `match` the correct validation type to use? Because I'm getting an error **Could not determine the embedded type for array "match"**

Comment: Yes @KingKongBigBong , you can use `match` validator for `String` types. It accepts array value for custom message. [Check Docs Here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-error-messages)